# C# login message warning

Tags: database, authentication

Well im here because i have a problem. i have code that was created a while ago. my code is working properly when i a user type the correct username and password. so my problem is when a user insert wrong username and password error message wont show. Here is my code:

```
MyDs.Clear();
MyDa.SelectCommand = Conn.CreateCommand();
MyDa.SelectCommand.CommandText = 
    "select * from PersonalName where Firstname=@first and Lastname=@last";
MyDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
MyDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@first", DbType.String, 25, "Firstname").Value = textbox_Username.Text;
MyDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@last", DbType.String, 25, "Lastname").Value = textbox_Password.Text;

MyDa.Fill(MyDs);
foreach (DataRow item in MyDs.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (textbox_Username.Text != item[1].ToString() || textbox_Password.Text != item[3].ToString())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("not connected");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connected");
    }
}
```

Anyone can tell me what is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataset will be empty if they put in the wrong username. This will be closer to what you want:

```
if (MyDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // you don't need to check username, the SQL query took care of that

    if (textbox_Password.Text == item[3].ToString())
        MessageBox.Show("Connected.");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Failed."); // wrong password
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Failed."); // no such user
```

Answer (score 0):

if the query returns no records becasue firast and last name aren't present, foreach doesn't execute nothing happens...

You need to test for myDa being empty as well, your code only works for checking valid users.

Comment: thank you for the logic. i tried the breakpoint, when i exucute the program the wrong information didnt check if it is wrong but it checked if it is right.